# How to rotate a list to given 'd positions in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I tried solving this problem on hackerrank where you are given a list `a` and an integer `d'`, you should rotate the list `a` to left `d` times and return the rotated list.

But, when I used this python code for `a =[1,2,3,4,5]` and `d = 4` I got the output as `[1,1,1,1,1]` instead of `[5,1,2,3,4]`.

```
temp = a
for j in range(len(a)):
    a[j-d] = temp[j]
return a
```

But when I explicitly copied each element of list 'a' into the list 'temp' it worked fine and I passed all the test cases.

```
temp = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    temp.append(a[i])
for j in range(len(a)):
    a[j-d]=temp[j]
return a
```

Can somebody explain what was wrong with the earlier code?? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set temp = a which indicate that they are referring to the same pointer
a simple check you could do is to check their memory address

```
id(temp)
id(a)
```

You will notice both temp and a referring to the same address therefore changes done on a will also affect temp and vice versa.

In your second method, you created a new list instead of assigning it using an existing list, therefore the address are not similar and they are not referencing one another.

Answer (score 1):

```
temp = a
```

This is a reference assignment. You merely created another reference pointing to the same underlying list object.

```
temp = a[:]
```

This will create a new object and assign `temp` to the new object. (So does your loop of explicitly copying)

This is because `list` is a mutable type in python - so new objects are not created upon assignment.

Comment: This explains the error in the code, so `+1`

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) is your friend for this:

```
import itertools
def rotate(l, n):
    it = itertools.cycle(l)
    for _ in range(n):
      next(it)
    return [next(it) for _ in range(len(l))]

print(rotate([1,2,3,4,5], 4))
```

result:

```
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/YoungDroopyFlatassembler)

Answer (score 0):

```
a =[1,2,3,4,5]
d = 4

for i in range(0,4):
    # repeat the below steps for d times
    temp=a[0] # store the a[0] in temp
    for j in range(0,len(a)-1):
        a[j]=a[j+1] # move all elements located in 1 to len(a)-1 to its previous location
    a[len(a)-1]=temp # store the temp in a[len(a)-1]
print(a)
```

output:

```
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```